# Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Good day, I have the following code in order to find the optimal algorithm:

```
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(gamma='auto')))
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    print(kfold)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
    print("asd")
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

where my X and y are :

```
X = dataset[['Twf', 'Depth']].values[:17655]
y = dataset['fr1'].values[:17655]
```

and i split them like

```
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
```

However i got the following error:

```
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models like LogisticRegression are classification models, which require your target feature to consist of classes or labels such as [0,1,2 ..] or [a,b,c ..] .

You would get the above error if your target consists of continues data, such as [1.236, 1.451, 2.213..]

Ensure the target feature has classes (either binary or multiclass)